# Compile citations from LaTeX to Markdown Text

Tags: latex, markdown, pandoc

I would like to use Pandoc (although any tool is fine) to compile a latex document into markdown text format. Right now I compile…

```
pandoc --bibliography=bibCourse.bib --wrap=preserve -o Syllabus.md Syllabus.tex
```

…with the command (any of the following)…

```
\cite{Label2020}
\fullcite{Label2020}
\textcite{Label2020}
```

…what comes out is…

```
@Label2020
```

I am pretty sure that's how the default compile is supposed to work, but not what I want. I want the output to be…

```
AuthorLast, AuthorFirst. Year. *Title* etc.
```

…in the text file. I have also tried adding various csl files which always yields the same result.

Comment: you could try going via HTML... something like: `pandoc --bibliography=bibCourse.bib Syllabus.tex -t html | pandoc -f html -t markdown`